# How to remove duplicated points from a layer originally with duplicated points in QGIS? (Accidentally copied and pasted)

Tags: qgis

Basically i accidentally copied and pasted the same links into the same layer instead of another layer which i didnt notice until the end.

I know this sounds similar to other duplicated points questions, but with mine, the layer ORIGINALLY had duplicated links in them. If it helps though, the duplicated links are of different directions with each other. I tried remove duplicate geometries but it only considered where the links are instead of what direction they're pointing, which means the duplicate links that are pointing different directions are also removed.

Is there a way to remove the copied and pasted duplicates by perhaps asking the system to remove 1/2 of the links on the layer so it recognises the previous duplicates (for e.g. 2 links -> copied and pasted became 4 -> QGIS removes half of all similar links on the map -> 2 links again)?

Comment: just a hint, but often the copied records will be grouped by ID, so you could use the ID to remove this group. Please specify the data format in your question as it might help;

Comment: Did you do anything special to get the lines to change direction? It could be useful to know how to do that...

Answer (score 2):

In the field calculator, you can create a new **virtual** field named `index`, and choose the value `$id` from the `Record` node in the right hand panel.

Pasted features get new row id's, so you will find the wrongly added lines at the bottom of the attribute table if sorted by the new `index`. Make sure to zoom to the extent of the layer before selecting and deleting those rows.

If your data already has a unique index column (e.g. a primary key), you could use that as well.

Comment: Could you please explain why you should "Make sure to zoom to the extent of the layer before selecting and deleting those rows." ... is it just in case the attribute table is set to ~"show only visible features"? Just wondering in case I've missed something else there.

Comment: Yes, my attribute table usually shows only visible features. If you work with huge datasets, it will get unusable slow otherwise.

Comment: Cheers. Maybe my 0.5-1gb datasets aren't actually that big, or I am just particularly patient (or silly). hehe ... but i'll think i'll try the tip.